# creating an array from xml data in c#

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, parsing

I have the following XML returned when I make an API call. I need to create an array that holds the `<status>` and `<description>` values for each of `<order_status>`, `<payment_status>`, and `<fulfillment_status>`. Can anyone share some knowledge that would help me?

```
<orderwave>
  <call_result>
    <order>
      <order_number>17377</order_number>
      <orderwave_order_number>RWD-336475921</orderwave_order_number>
      <order_status>
        <status>active</status>
        <description>This order is free to be charged and shipped.  It is open in the orderwave workflow.</description>
      </order_status>
      <payment_status>
        <status>declined</status>
        <description>This order has been declined by the payment network.</description>
      </payment_status>
      <fulfillment_status>
        <status>not shipped</status>
        <description>This order has not been allocated for shipment.</description>
      </fulfillment_status>
    </order>
  </call_result>
  <warning_count>0</warning_count>
  <warnings/>
  <error_count>0</error_count>
  <errors/>
</orderwave>
```

Comment: What would be the type of the objects stored in this array? do you want to simply break down the XML into smaller XDocuments or do you want a more strongly typed approach?

Comment: You should use linqToXML probably

Comment: Take a look at using a `List<T>`, with `T` being an object to hold the data you want, and then use LINQ to XML to parse the document into the List.  If I get time later I'll post an example.

Answer (score 0):

LinqToXML is what you want I believe.

I haven't done this in a while so my syntax might not be perfect.

Something like this:

```
var xmlSource = contacts.Load(@"../../return.xml");

var q = xmlSource.Descendants("order").SelectMany(x => x.Elements("order_status")
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my earlier comment, an easy and quick way to do this is with [`List<T> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Use a class to hold the data for each order - for example:

```
public class Order
{

    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string OrderDescription { get; set; }
    public string PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public string PaymentDescription { get; set; }
    public string FulfillmentStatus { get; set; }
    public string FulfillmentDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Next, you can load the XML into an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), parse it with LINQ to XML and create a List of Order objects:

```
// Parse the XML string; you can also load the XML from a file.
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<orderwave>....</orderwave>");

// Get a collection of elements under each order node
var orders = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("order")
// Use the data for each order node to create a new instance of the order class
              select new Order
              {
                  OrderNumber = ConvertTo.Int32(x.Element("order_number").Value),
                  OrderStatus = x.Element("order_status").Element("status").Value,
                  OrderDescription = x.Element("order_status").Element("description").Value,
                  PaymentStatus = x.Element("payment_status").Element("status").Value,
                  PaymentDescription = x.Element("payment_status").Element("description").Value,
                  FulfillmentStatus = x.Element("fulfillment_status").Element("status").Value,
                  FulfillmentDescription = x.Element("fulfillment_status").Element("description").Value
              }).ToList();
          // Convert the result to a list of Order objects
```

This is off the top of my head without testing it, but it should point you in the right direction if you want to use Lists instead of arrays.